# `ln -s` creates a symlink inside an existing folder instead of failing?

Tags: symlink

`$mkdir lnTest1 lnTest2`

`$ln -s lnTest1 "lnTest2"` There is NO slash at the end of "lnTest2"!!

```
$ls lnT* -Rl |sed "s'$USER''g"
lnTest1:
total 0

lnTest2:
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1   7 Jun 22 22:48 lnTest1 -> lnTest1
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I was trying a way to ask a question without wording it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the last argument to `ln` is a directory, the links are made in that directory. The man page says:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>     ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY     (3rd form)
> ```
>
> In the 3rd and 4th forms, create links to each TARGET in DIRECTORY.

It doesn't matter whether you're creating a hard or symbolic link. `cp` and `mv` behave similarly.

Comment: I think than an `alias ln='ln -T'` could be a workaround, but then it would fail if I want an actual directory be recognized as such; And even if I use `/` at the end, it still doesnt accept the directory... so the best is know about `-T` ln option and use it properly, I just saw `cp` and `mv` have the same option for the exactly same purpose, thx!